# outside array not affected from function appending within

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, numbers

I am working with arrays and I created a function that appends an array from within. However when I print the array, it still appears empty. What gives?

```
    var queriesFinal : [String] = []

func queryValidator(search : String)
{
    var letterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefgjhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ")
    var numberSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "1234567890".uppercaseString)
    var queriesTwo : [String] = search.lowercaseString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(letterSet)

    for(var x = 0; x < queriesTwo.count; x++)
    {
        for(var y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            var str = String(y)
            if(queriesTwo[x] == str)
            {
                var numberStr = String(queriesTwo[x]) + "th"
                queriesFinal.append(numberStr)
            }
        }
    }
}


println(queriesFinal)

search = "Matt 8th"

queryValidator(search)
```

This code can run in playground..

I appreciate any help!

Comment: what's the expected result and how it differs?

Comment: is this statement executing: var numberStr = String(queriesTwo[x]) + "th"?

Comment: I'm trying to make a function that finds all the numbers in a string then puts each of them in the new array with "th" added to them... its for a search bar project I'm making if that helps. Yes, that statement executes.. the "queriesFinal" isnt just getting appended

Comment: So, `queriesFinal` is supposed to be `["8th"]`, right? If you move your `println(queriesFinal)` line _after_ `queryValidator(search)`, that's what you'll get.

Comment: "1234567890".uppercaseString ???

Comment: @Zaph left-over code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Mike S, you've made a small mistake println should be after your queryValidator, I've also added an optional in case your queryValidator search returns nil, also as mentioned by Zaph you don't need numberSet, so I removed it:

```
func queryValidator(search : String) -> [String]? {
    let queriesTwo:[String] = search.lowercaseString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefgjhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "))
    var queriesResult:[String] = []
    for x in 0...queriesTwo.count-1 {
        for y in 0...9 {
            if(queriesTwo[x] == String(y)) {
                queriesResult.append(String(queriesTwo[x]) + "th")
            }
        }
    }
    return queriesResult.count > 0 ? queriesResult : nil
}
var search = "Matt 8 less7"
if let queriesFinal = queryValidator(search) {
    println(queriesFinal)
} else {
    println("no result")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I knew a part of it was a syntax error. This is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach with Regular Expressions:

```
func queryValidator(search: String) -> [String] {
    var queriesFinal:[String] = []

    var nsSearch: NSString = search
    let pattern = "(\\d+)"
    var regEx = NSRegularExpression(pattern:pattern, options:nil, error:nil)

    regEx?.enumerateMatchesInString(nsSearch, options:nil, range:NSMakeRange(0, nsSearch.length), usingBlock: { (result, flags, stop) in
        let found = nsSearch.substringWithRange(result.range)
        queriesFinal.append("\(found)th")
    })
    return queriesFinal
}

var result = queryValidator(search)
println("result: \(result)")
```

Output:

> result: [8th, 7th, 6th]

For information on regular expressions see: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Comment: This definitely does the job I needed! although the whole code seems very alien to me. I guess I need to study some more haha. I'm going to look back on this for references to figure out what some of these lines mean. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I added a link to regular expressions. Basically it is fancy pattern matching. The meaning of (\\d+) The \\d matches digits, the + means one or more, the outer parentheses mean capture. There are double \ because of string rules.